# Is Android Navigation drawer supposed to be over ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, material-design, android-drawer

As the title suggests, my app uses a side menu using navigation drawer. I got inspired by [this official google doc](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon) and its nav drawer can be toggled either by swipe from left to right or by clicking on modified home icon on top left of ActionBar.

When nav drawer is drawn, the drawer icon in Actionbar is replaced by back button which in change closes the drawer and returns actionbar to its original state.

But this is where I find problems. As in [this different official google doc about material design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android-) it is clearly stated that drawer should be over actionbar covering it.

I checked e.g. gmail app uses the latter, i.e. drawer over ActionBar.

Should I follow guidelines #1 or #2?

Comment: Honestly I think you should do whatever makes more sense to the app. There are suggestions out there but it may not apply to your app. Following convention is a great thing, but it shouldn't break the natural life cycle of your app's behavior. Do what you think (or what people would think) is natural.

Comment: I want app to feel native and to in compliance with material design guidelines. The elevation of drawer is defined sth at one place and sth else at other in google docs. I am more inclined to drawer over ab as thats what gmail uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The wonderful think about standards is that there are so many to choose from." *— Admiral Grace Hopper*

I'll start by pointing out that the first link you referenced that talks about closing the drawer by clicking the icon is pre-Material Design.  So my choice would be to go with the Material Design-specific recommendation.

Now take a look at this:

[The Many Faces Of Google's Hamburger Navigation Drawer | Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/30/google-turns-design-inconsistency-ten-latest-round-navigation-drawers/)

Material Navigation Drawer isn't even consistent within Google's own apps.

I think some UX people feel that there should still be a single-touch way to close the drawer in addition to the swipe.  Looks like even the dev teams within Google can't come to a consensus.

So consider all your options, then do what makes the most sense for your app.